# Ionic(Capacitor) - How to view image after capturing it?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am able to capture an image with ionic capacitor and convert it to a base 64 string so I can send it to the API. But how do I show the image on the HTML side after capturing it so the user can see it before it is uploaded?

Below is the code when I click on the submit button

```
  CreateMainStore(MainStoreForm: FormGroup) {
    const mainStore: MainStoreModel = MainStoreForm.value;
    let formData = new FormData();
    // formData.append("mainStoreId", mainStore.mainStoreId.toString());
    formData.append("mainStoreName", mainStore.mainStoreName);
    formData.append("imageTitle", mainStore.imageTitle);
    formData.append("mainStoreLogo", this.Logo);

    var object = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      object[key] = value;
    });
    var json = JSON.stringify(object);

    this.dataService.AddMainStore(mainStore);
    this.router.navigate([""]);
  } // Create MainStore
```

This is the code I use to capture the image and store it in a Logo variable

```
  async selectImageSource() {
    const buttons = [
      {
        text: "Take Photo",
        icon: "camera",
        handler: () => {
          this.addImage(CameraSource.Camera);
        },
      },
      {
        text: "Gallery",
        icon: "image",
        handler: () => {
          this.addImage(CameraSource.Photos);
        },
      },
    ];

    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      header: "Select Image Source",
      buttons,
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  } // End of select image source

  async addImage(source: CameraSource) {
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 60,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      height: 128,
      direction: CameraDirection.Rear,
      source,
    });
    this.Logo = image.base64String;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file just try

```
<img [src]="Logo"/>
```

it will show the image

Comment: This is not working for me. I believe it would have worked if I had the image before hand, but I do not.

Comment: I haven't tried it with capacitor yet, i tried it with cordova camera plugin and it worked with me, can you try my solution ?!, if there is an error let me know and we can solve it

Comment: I got it working, but I had to add extra code. 
  transformer() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.Logo);
  }

so I am not sure if I should accept your answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

First I needed to import :

```
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

Next I prepended `"data:image;base64,"` to the base64 string that I received from the Camera plugin.

Then I needed to sanitize `this.logo` by making use of the following method:

```
  transformer() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.Logo);
  }
```

lastly I made use of the above answer from "Edmad Abodou" to call the method using the img tag:

```
<img [src]="transformer()" />
``

And this allowed me to view the image after the user uploaded it.
```